# Homomorphisms, Kernel and Image

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, proof-verification, finite-groups, group-homomorphism

I have two questions here, I believe I did them correctly I just want to make sure.

> 1. Find all homomorphisms from $Z_4$ to $Z_6$
> 2. Let $θ$ : ($Z_9$ ,·) → ($Z11)$,·) be a non-trivial homomorphism. Find all elements of $\ker(θ)$ and $\operatorname{Im}(θ)$

For #1 let $Φ$ be from $Z_4$ to $Z_6$.  Since  $\gcd(4,6)=2$ then there are 2 homomorphisms.  We see $4*Φ(1)=(1+1+1+1)=Φ(0)$ so the order of $Φ(1)$ has to divide $4$.  Since $Φ(1)$ exists in $\Bbb Z_6$, the order of $Φ$(1) has to divide $6$ as well.  So the order of $Φ(1)$ has to be either $1$ or $2$.  The only element in $\Bbb Z_6$ of order $1$ is $0$ and there is only one element of order $2$ in $\Bbb Z_6$ and that is $3$.  Thus $Φ(1)=0$ or $3$.

For #2 since $θ$ is a homomorphism then by the 1st iso thm $\Bbb Z_9/\ker(θ)$ is isomorphic to $\operatorname{Im}(θ)$.  The $|\operatorname{Im}(θ)|$ divides$\gcd(9,11)$ which is $1$.  Hence  $|\operatorname{Im}(θ)|=1$.  By Lagrange's Thm $|\Bbb Z_9/\ker(θ)|=|\operatorname{Im}(θ)|$ which we see is $9/|\ker(θ)|=1$ hence $|\ker(θ)|=9$ and $\ker(θ)=\Bbb Z_9$.

If there is any mistakes or anything that should be added?

Comment: 1. Correct. 2. I think the dot suggests to take the *multiplicative* groups, with $6$ and $10$ elements, respectively.

Comment: What do you mean by this, do you mean to say the Image is equal to e and the ker is $Z_9$ which I stated above?

Comment: I mean, the notation $(\Bbb Z_9,\cdot)$ suggests me that it's the group of coprimes to $9$ modulo $9$ (these are $6$ numbers) with *multiplication* as group operation.